# How would I translate this sentence into a predicate formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

A dragon is green if at least one of its parents is green

I have

```
∀X⋅dragon(X) ∧ green (X) ⇒ ∃Y⋅childOf(Y,X)∧green(X)
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > "A dragon is green if at least one of its parents is green"
>
> I have:
>   $$\forall X\cdot\color{silver}{\Big(}\textsf{dragon}(X) ∧ \textsf{green} (X) ⇒ ∃Y⋅\color{silver}{\big(}\textsf{childOf}(Y,X)∧\textsf{green}(X)\color{silver}{\big)\Big)}$$

No, you said: "Everything that is a dragon and green, will be green and has a child."†   That is *assuming* that the scope of the universal is meant to encompass the entire line as I've indicated.

(† I read $\textsf{childOf}(Y,X)$ as "$Y$ is a child of $X$")

---

*Note:* the required sentence is of the form: "$A$ if $B$", not "$A$ only if $B$".

You want to say: "Everything, which is a dragon and has a parent who is green, will be green."

> $$\forall X~\Big( \textsf{dragon}(X)\wedge \exists Y~\big(\textsf{childOf}(X,Y)\wedge\textsf{green}(Y)\big)\;\to\;\textsf{green}(X)\Big) \\[2ex] \forall X~\forall Y~\Big( \big(\textsf{dragon}(X)\wedge \textsf{childOf}(X,Y)\wedge\textsf{green}(Y)\big)\;\to\;\textsf{green}(X)\Big)$$

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Would you happen to know any resources where I can read up more on logic as in turning sentences into predicate formulas and creating formal proofs for propositional logic? I am really struggling with it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I think your implication is backwards. The formula you have written says that every green dragon must be the child of another green dragon.

Comment: so how would I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

No. You assert that every green dragon $X$ has a parent, and that $X$ is green. Assuming the final green(X) is a typo for green(Y), you assert that every green dragon has a green parent, which again could be false: there's no reason a green dragon should have green parents.

Comment: ∀Y⋅childOf(Y,X)∧green(Y) ⇒  ∃X dragon(X) ∧ Green (X) is this one correct ? @Patrick

Comment: You have an unquantified X in childOf(Y, X), so no.

Comment: should i replace the Y with the X in that case?

Comment: Why would you? What would that yield?

Comment: i think that would translate it as if Y is a child of X and Y is green, then there is exists a X that is green. @Patrick